# Overload Resolution: What is the role of explicit and the initialization syntax?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, explicit

Suppose I have an immutable `String` class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class String
{
public:
    explicit String(const char *Value) : Size(std::strlen(Value)), Value(new char[Size + 1])
    {
        std::memcpy(this->Value, Value, Size + 1);
        std::cout << Value << ", novice." << Size << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename T, std::size_t N> String(const T (&Value)[N]) : Size(N - 1), Value(new char[N])
    {
        std::memcpy(this->Value, Value, N);
        std::cout << Value << ", expert." << Size << std::endl;
    }
    ~String()
    {
        delete[] Value;
    }
private:
    const std::size_t Size;
    char *Value;
};

void main()
{
    auto &s = "Welcome to C++";
    String string = s;
    String str {s};
    String st(s);
    return;
}
```

I want to know the role `explicit` plays and how the initialization syntax makes a difference when the constructor overload is chosen.

---

I understand that for `str` and `st`, I am explicitly calling the constructor that takes a pointer to `const char`, so they print out:

```
Welcome to C++, novice.
Welcome to C++, novice.
```

But I don't understand why for `string`

```
Welcome to C++, expert.
```

is printed out. Please clarify how the overload is being selected.

Comment: Your string class is only immutable if you initialize it with another immutable C-style string. If you have a non-constant array of characters and create a `String` object from that array, then you can still modify the array and the supposedly immutable `String` object will also change.

Comment: I realized that right now. Thanks!

Comment: @BoPersson I do not think that dupe is right.  It  plays a part but there is other things going on here as well.

Comment: @Nathan - I think the answers to the other question is a very good match, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/121216/597607) using `explicit String`and everything. But you guys can reopen if you don't agree.

Comment: Fixed, String is now immutable and slow. ;)

Comment: I did use `new` in the constructor initializer-list, and copied the string.  Is it bad to do `new` in initializer list?

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar Oops.  I missed that.  I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
String str {s};
String st(s);
```

The

```
explicit String(const char *Value)
```

The reason the pointer overload is chosen is because it is not templated.  Both the pointer and the array constructors are considered as an exact match to `s` so it would be an ambiguity but since the array constructor is a template it is consider less of a match then the pointer constructor.  Even if you removed the `explicit` the pointer overload would still be chosen.

Now with

```
String string = s;
```

`explicit` does matter because `s` is not a `String`.  This means the compiler needs to implicitly convert it to one so it chooses the array constructor as it is an exact match and the only viable constructor as explicit constructors cannot be used in implicit conversions.

Comment: So without `explicit` the pointer overload would be called since it is non-templated?

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar Yes, because the template has a lower precedence then the pointer constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.